# List of unique pairs, which are in columns A,B but not in C,D (set A - set B)

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a list of pairs, which are unique from summed A,B and C,D columns.

So if A,B contains (aaa, 111) and C,D contains (aaa, 111), this pair will not be in result. But if A,B contains (aaa, 111) and C,D contains(aaa,000) or (bbb,111) etc. this value will be in result.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP to FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A1:B6,ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A6&B1:B6,D1:D4&E1:E4,1,0)))
```

[image]